# How can I use myname.stackoverflow.com as my blog? I used other blogs, but Stack Overflow would be very nice for coders to write blogs

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, blogging

Dear Stack Overflow and moderators, may I request to delete this thread? I did not mean to be evil, I am a Stack Overflow fan and just requested a feature, but I don't want to put my numbers down to -50K.
Please delete this thread, I will really appreciate it.

### [closed request]

Is there any Stack Overflow blog such as the other free blogs, to build our own blogs using Stack Overflow?

Everything should remain as it is, but simply while posting, we could select a **blog post**, and it goes to my http://myname.stackoverflow.com/my-blog-bla-bla-bla

Note: a very nice feature of Stack Overflow is the code detection, which highlights code and shows it in a very plain and simple way, which I really would like to use in my article blog.

Comment: Stack Overflow (thankfully) doesn't offer this functionality - your [user summary](http://stackoverflow.com/users/285594/iamson0fraja) and [network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/7a299d19-d098-413e-9807-47b1fc65a388) pages are as close to a "blog" that you have. (There's also the [careers 2.0](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) site, having thought about it.)

Comment: @IamSon0fRaja It *really wouldn't* be great to have it, IMHO. SO does what it does very, very well - why needlessly shift the focus elsewhere?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't intended to be a blog. It's a Q&A site. Why should they host your blog for free?

Comment: **YOU'RE GENIUS!**

Comment: @YOU - Erm, what? I feel like I missed the joke...

Comment: No, it is most definitely **not** "already almost a blog". It's a Q&A site. Neither your questions nor your answers should even *remotely* resemble a blog. You might want to read the FAQ; Stack Overflow is a fusion of a lot of different things, but a blog is not one of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you like the Stack Overflow editor, why not [use it in WordPress](http://vonlind.com/wordpress-plugins/wmd-editor-wordpress-plugin/)? As I understand it, the Stack Overflow editor [was originally WMD](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/reverse-engineering-the-wmd-editor/), but the Stack Overflow team wanted to make some changes to it, so now it is WMD+modifications.

I also hear [Forrst](http://forrst.com/) is the latest web-[1337](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet).0 platform for programmers to do the whole social thing. I don't use it, I simply read about it somewhere.

Answer (score 8):

You can't. As I've alluded to in the comments, Stack Overflow doesn't offer this functionality.

You can harness Stack Overflow via your [user summary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285594/iamson0fraja) (where you can enter a description of yourself, etc.) the [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/7a299d19-d098-413e-9807-47b1fc65a388) pages and indeed the [careers 2.0](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) site), but there's (thankfully) no "blog" facility.

My personal thoughts on this are that Stack Overflow does what it does very, very well - attempting to become a "jack of all trades" would be a very odd move that would dilute the main offering and I'd be very surprised if this was ever seriously considered.

That said, I'm just another user - others may well disagree.